# how to change the selected text font-family in div on click on different button of font family

Tags: jquery, editor

I have made a div editable and want to select some portion of text and wanted to change its font-family on clicking on different font-family buttons.
it changes but keeps the earlier selection also

`$('#message_div').on('selectstart', function () {
            $(document).one('mouseup', function() {
                st = this.getSelection();
                var range = st.getRangeAt(0);
                var newNode = document.createElement("span");
                newNode.setAttribute("class", "selectedText");
                range.surroundContents(newNode);
                $(".selectedText").focus();
            });
        });
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't listen to the "select" event, instead listen to the "click" events thrown by your buttons.

The code should be something like that :

```
$('.btn-font-change').click(function() {
    // Browsers compat
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
    }

    var newNode = document.createElement("span");
    newNode.setAttribute("class", "selectedText");

    range.surroundContents(newNode);
    $(".selectedText").focus();
});
```

Is it working? If not, can you create a jsfiddle that reproduce your page?